# How acceptable is it to use 'tu' for someone you call 'madame', 'mademoiselle' or 'monsieur' ?

Tags: usage, pronoms, langage-informel

Normally it should be *vous avez besoin de ... , monsieur*.

But is it possible to say *tu as besoin de ... , monsieur* in any context without being rude to the other person or without being considered uneducated? Does it make a difference for 'madame' or 'mademoiselle' ?

Answer (score 7):

It is not acceptable at all. Those civility titles imply respect, distance and always a minimum of  formality ; the use of the second person singular, which reflects always a certain degree of familiarity with which the two persons treat one another, is incompatible with the terms of address "madame", "mademoiselle" and "monsieur".
However,  someone unaware of this fact  can safely err and use the second person singular as well as one of those terms; there is nothing rude implied, no insult; people usually understand that the person given to such usage has not yet become conscious of this  convention. The failure to abide by this principle is characteristic only of people of origin other than French.

Comment: I wonder how much of this "convention" applies to Francophones who are not from France. I'm thinking of Francophones from Belgium Quebec and Africa where saying *tu* connotes differently than it does in France.

Comment: @None I don't have the least idea about that except that given the fact that those ethnic groups, presumably cognizant with French culture since they learn its language,   should, it seems,  be aware of it. I think there is no such question to be ask in the case of European countries (Belgium, Switzerland) and Canada; I am thinking rather of Africa, the West Indies, Tahiti, Madagascar, …

Comment: [_Vouvoiement et tutoiement_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140) (BDL). Sommaire et pas sur le français, mais tout de même : [lien](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01413720). Et [_plus_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutoiement_et_vouvoiement#En_fran%C3%A7ais). Mais [_encore_](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langage-et-societe-2004-2-page-27.htm). Ou [_aussi_](https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-02363817/document). Je pense qu'il y a davantage à dire là-dessus.

Comment: @LPH I strongly doubt that all native Quebecers, Bruxellois or of the Central African Republic (to name only a few) will use or even be aware of the culture of France when using & speaking what is to them native French. They learn whatever cultural habits predominate in their own countries first.

Comment: @None Your point of view recalls me to a reality that I had come to perceive some time ago, but which I didn't take into account in my comments, and that is that in fact the Canadians wouldn't to a great extent read much French literature and would get most of the inspiration for their French from Canadian literature, which is understandable. It is but a step to generalization and I think I can relate to what you mean.

Comment: In Belgium at least, with the exception of real "Brusseleer" or kids, people wouldn't generally mix "tu" and "monsieur" in the same sentence

Comment: @LaurentS. Do you mean mixing by mistake, or is it Brusseleer's deliberate and standard way of using it? What is the opinion of French on Brusseleers? I also wonder if kids use 'tu' and 'monsieur' at the same time towards an elder, i.e. their grandfathers. If a kid uses it that way on purpose what does it mean?

Comment: @Xfce4 I've very often heard young children mix *tu* and *Monsieur* or *Madame* or *Maîtresse* or *Maître* . Quite normal before they learn the rules in a formal way. That's for France.

Comment: Brusseleer are using it on purpose, because polite "vous" is not used too much by brusseleers. Kids use it more by "mistake" I would say, even though it's a cute mistake :-)

Comment: [*Monsieur le maire, tu as raison*](https://generation-avenir.typepad.fr/gnration_avenir/2016/02/vm-17-2-2016-les-serpents-de-mer-de-lam%C3%A9lioration-de-nos-d%C3%A9placements-dans-le-golfe-de-saint-tropez-.html#comment-6a00e55222a746883401bb08bba264970d)